# ChartObject Runtime Error that suddenly appears after month

Tags: excel, vba, range, runtime, excel-charts

I am trying to create a Chart. Once it worked. Tried it again some weeks later and now error in this following first line. It says "Runtime error 1004 - Application or object-defined error." in Line Set Co = Work.....

There is more code to the folling, but here the failure appears.

```
Set CO = Worksheets("Ausgabe").ChartObjects.Add(200, 10, 500, 350)
Set CH = CO.Chart
CH.ChartType = xlXYScatterSmoothNoMarkers
CH.SetSourceData Source:=Unionrng
CH.SeriesCollection(1).Name = "Dichtefunktion"
For i = 2 To a
CH.SeriesCollection(i).AxisGroup = xlSecondary
CH.SeriesCollection(i).ChartType = xlColumnClustered
```

Comment: There is nothing inherently wrong with `Set CO = Worksheets("Ausgabe").ChartObjects.Add(200, 10, 500, 350)` so we probably need to see the rest of the code.

Comment: Therefor i have to manipulate it a bit, because of business rules/compliance regulation. Will upload it on Monday! Thanks btw.

Answer (score 0):

So this is the complete code from the sub. hope this will help. The pricate Sub wil be called from in the main Sub activated by an button.

```
Private Sub VisualisierungNormalverteilung()
    
    'Building a normaldistribution

    Dim CO As ChartObject
    Dim CH As Chart
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim a As Integer
    Dim b As String
    Dim XW As Range
    Dim DV As Range
    Dim Sigma As Range
    Dim Soll As Range
    Dim Tol As Range
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim Unionrng As Range
    
    'Diagrammauswahl treffen / create Range
    
    Set XW = (Worksheets("Daten").Range("F2:F" & (WorksheetFunction.Count(Worksheets("Daten").Range("F:F")) - 1)))
    Set DV = (Worksheets("Daten").Range("D2:D" & (WorksheetFunction.Count(Worksheets("Daten").Range("D:D")) - 1)))
    Set Sigma = (Worksheets("Daten").Range("G2:G" & (WorksheetFunction.Count(Worksheets("Daten").Range("G:G")) - 1)))
    Set Soll = (Worksheets("Daten").Range("H2:H" & (WorksheetFunction.Count(Worksheets("Daten").Range("H:H")) - 1)))
    Set Tol = (Worksheets("Daten").Range("I2:I" & (WorksheetFunction.Count(Worksheets("Daten").Range("I:I")) - 1)))
    Set Unionrng = Union(XW, DV)
    a = 1
    If Worksheets("ZE").Range("G6").Value <> Empty Then
        Set Unionrng = Union(Unionrng, Sigma)
        a = a + 1
        Worksheets("ZE").Range("J" & a).Value = "+/- " & Worksheets("ZE").Range("C3").Value & "-Sigma-Grenze"
    End If
    If Worksheets("ZE").Range("G3").Value <> Empty Then
        Set Unionrng = Union(Unionrng, Soll)
        a = a + 1
        Worksheets("ZE").Range("J" & a).Value = "Sollgröße"
    End If
    If Worksheets("ZE").Range("C1").Value <> Empty Or Worksheets("ZE").Range("C2").Value <> Empty Then
        Set Unionrng = Union(Unionrng, Tol)
        a = a + 1
        Worksheets("ZE").Range("J" & a).Value = "Toleranzgrenzen"
    End If
    
    'Zeichnen der Normalverteilung mit den Datenreihen / Create Chart
        
    Set CO = Worksheets("Ausgabe").ChartObjects.Add(200, 10, 500, 350)
    Set CH = CO.Chart
        CH.ChartType = xlXYScatterSmoothNoMarkers
        CH.SetSourceData Source:=Unionrng
        CH.SeriesCollection(1).Name = "Dichtefunktion"
    For i = 2 To a
        'CH.SeriesCollection(i).AxisGroup = xlSecondary
        'CH.SeriesCollection(i).ChartType = xlColumnClustered
    Next i

    'Formatierung der Säulen für Markierungen / formatting the Chart
    
    For i = 2 To a
        CH.SeriesCollection(i).Name = Worksheets("ZE").Range("J" & i).Value
    Next i
    For i = 2 To a
    With CH.FullSeriesCollection(i).Format.Line
        .Visible = msoFalse
        .Visible = msoTrue
        .Weight = 3
        .ForeColor.RGB = RGB(0 + (28 * i), 0 + (50 * i), 0)
    End With
    CH.SeriesCollection(i).Interior.Color = RGB(0 + (28 * i), 0 + (50 * i), 0)
    Next i
    
    'Benneung der Elemente / Ausblenden des zweiten Koordinatensystems / naming some elements and hiding secound coordinatesystem
     
    CH.HasTitle = True
    If Worksheets("ZE").Range("G2").Value <> Empty Then
        b = ": " + Worksheets("ZE").Range("G2").Value
    Else
        b = " "
    End If
    CH.ChartTitle.Text = "Normalverteilung" + b
    CH.HasLegend = True
    CH.Legend.Position = xlLegendPositionBottom
    CH.HasAxis(xlValue, xlSecondary) = Not (CH.HasAxis(xlValue, xlSecondary))
    
    'Formatierung / more formatting
    
    CO.Chart.PlotArea.Select
        Selection.Width = 435
        Selection.Left = 20
        Selection.Height = 260
    With CH.Axes(xlCategory)
         .HasTitle = True
         .AxisTitle.Text = "Messwerte"
         .AxisTitle.Left = 235
         .AxisTitle.Top = 300
         .TickLabels.Orientation = xlTickLabelOrientationUpward
         .MinimumScale = WorksheetFunction.Min(Worksheets("Daten").Range("F:F").Value)
         .MaximumScale = WorksheetFunction.Max(Worksheets("Daten").Range("F:F").Value)
    End With
    With CH.Axes(xlValue)
         .HasTitle = True
         .AxisTitle.Text = "Wahrscheinlichkeit"
         .AxisTitle.Left = 30
         .AxisTitle.Top = 120
         .MinimumScale = 0
         .MaximumScale = WorksheetFunction.Max(Worksheets("Daten").Range("D:D")) + (WorksheetFunction.Max(Worksheets("Daten").Range("D:D")) * 0.2)
    End With
    
    
             
End Sub
```

Calling Sub

```
Sub NAuswerten()

    'activated by Button
    
    If WorksheetFunction.Count(Worksheets("Eingabe").Range("A:A")) >= 10 Then
        
        'Starten der Unterprozeduren / call subs
        
        DatenuebergebenNormalverteilung
        AufbereitenNormalverteilung
        KalkulationNormalverteilung
        VisualisierungNormalverteilung
        InformationsboxNormalverteilung
        Verteilungsfunktion
        
        'Tabellenblattwechsel / changing the sheets
        
        Worksheets("Ausgabe").Visible = True
        Worksheets("Ausgabe").Activate
        Worksheets("Eingabe").Visible = False
    End If
End Sub
```

The other called functions are just handling the Data. I already checked the result. Everything is fine.